# What exactly are "suitcase handles" in a cockpit?

Tags: terminology, accident-investigation

I was watching [Seconds From Disaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seconds_From_Disaster) about [Alaska Airlines 261](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alaska_Airlines_Flight_261) (the one with the horizontal stabilizer issue) and at one point the copilot tells the pilot to "try the suitcase handles". Is that pilot slang for something or did I maybe hear it wrong? (Seconds From Disaster uses actual cockpit recordings for the recreations, so I don't think it's made up or anything.)

Comment: The issue was with the horizontal stabiliser, not the vertical.

Comment: Edited by changing “vertical” to “horizontal”.

Answer (score 15):

From the [NTSB report](http://www.ntsb.gov/investigations/AccidentReports/Reports/AAR0201.pdf)

> "Suitcase handles" is a colloquial term for the longitudinal trim handles located on the center control
>   pedestal. "Pickle switches" is a colloquial term for the trim switches located on the outboard side of each of
>   the control wheels.

The [MD-80 cockpit](http://www.hilmerby.com/md80/md_pedfwd.html) is shown at this page, with the trim handles on the left side of the console (item 9).

[image]

Under normal operation, the pilot will use the switches on the control column to change the trim.  If there's a problem with the thumb switches, the handles on the console are available.